# Android - getHost() returns null if URL has #

Tags: java, android, uri

I have some URLs' in string form, and from these URLs' I want to generate a URI using `java.net.URI`.

These URLs' are actually hyperlinks in an Android `Webview`:

`clc://C#`    or    `clc://C++`

```
final URI u = new URI(newURL);              
final String sScheme = u.getScheme();
final String sHost = u.getHost();
final String sPath = u.getPath();
```

But in the above code, if a URL has `#` or `+` then `getHost()` returns null.

I tried to encode the URL as follows, but it doesn't work:

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

I also tried putting `%23` for `#`, then too it doesn`t work.

Please help me to resolve this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLEncoder` doesn't always provide the correct output, especially when URIs' are involved.

Try the following approach instead:

```
Uri u = Uri.parse(newURL)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("param", param)
                .build();

String url = u.toString();
```

where `param` is a web service parameter (if using any). This will encode the URL in UTF-8 format correctly. Then,

```
final String sScheme = u.getScheme( );
final String sHost = u.getHost( );
final String sPath = u.getPath( );
```

It will work as expected.